# How to use Grails dataSource in resources.groovy?

Tags: spring, configuration, grails

I have an external java library I am using in my Grails project.  It needs a DataSource via the Spring configuration.  However, the dataSource appears to not be accessible from resources.groovy.  How do I get access to it?  I'm using the following in resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
 eventDao(com.JavaClassRequiringDataSource) {
  //dataSource = ref(dataSource, true)
  dataSource = dataSource
 }
}
```

Running the app results in a exception:

> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException:
>   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException:
>   No such property: dataSource for
>   class: grails.spring.BeanBuilder

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to http://www.grails.org/Spring+Bean+Builder your method should be right.. I just did some Googleing and found that this should do it (untested):

```
beans = {
 eventDao(com.JavaClassRequiringDataSource) {
  dataSource = ref('dataSource', true)
 }
}
```

so you do not reference it by variable, but by name. (Source: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?cat=23)

Comment: That did it!  The docs show examples like so:

anotherBean(AnotherBean) {
   example = ref("${beanName}Bean"
}

Which with the ${} makes you think they are just de-aliasing the variable name.

Comment: For some of the beans I'm wiring, I found it best to just do `ref('dataSource')`. Adding the second argument to ref threw errors that Grails couldn't set the bean dataSource while the bean dataSource was being defined.